# Not getting performance with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Map-reduce and I am using Hadoop Pipes.
     I have an input file which contains the number of records, one per line. I have written one simple program to print those lines in which three words are common. In map function I have emitted the word as a key and record as a value and compared those records in reduce function.
     Then I compared Hadoop's performance with simple C++ program in which I read the records from file and split it into words and load the data in map. Map contains word as a key and record as a value. After loading all the data, I compared that data.
     But I found that for doing the same task Hadoop Map-reduce takes long time compared with plain C++ program. When I run my program on hadoop it takes about 37 minutes where as it takes only about 5 minutes for simple C++ program.
     Please, somebody help me to figure out whether I am doing wrong somewhere? Our application needs performance.

Comment: I agree with Gruzman's anwer, but you should also try doing the word/record comparison in the map function. This minimizes the network traffic when transferring from map to reduce, which is often the bottleneck. I'd expect this to cut the run time, providing a more realistic comparison (assuming you're not using reducer also as the combiner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points which should be made here: 
Hadoop is not high performance - it is scalable. Local program doing the same on small data set will always outperform hadoop. So its usage makes sense only when you want to run on cluster on machine and enjoy Hadoop's parallel processing.
Hadoop streaming is also not best thing performance wise since there are task switches per line. In many cases native hadoop program written in Java will have  better performance

Comment: Then what is the use of parallel processing and using cluster of machines?

Comment: Let say today your local version runs 6 times faster. Lets assume you use all the CPU. So from cluster of 6 machines you will be on break even. In practice hadoop makes sense when you have serious data volumes and want to process it in parralel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also need to know where the output of map function get stored? Can we know the location of that output?

Comment: It is stored on HDFS, you set it when run the job

Comment: Actually I need to know the output and location of only map function. It is stored on HDFS but can I know the location and get that data after job completion?

Comment: Intermidiate results are stored in local file system and deleted after  job is finished. If you need them - run job w/o reducers and they will became output

Comment: OK. Thank for your help. Now, I will try to run the job without reducer.